# PrimeNg treeTable how to change routing url and how to add onNodeSelect event only for child node

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-treetable

I have couple of questions on `primeng` `treeTable`,

1. I see that the `expand` link in `treedata.js` is `/#` but I want to
   change it to different routing links. In my case here it should be
   `/productsummary`. I added it in `treedata.js` and working fine but I am using `treeTable` in other route which is `/ordersSummary` so is there any attribute to use to change the routing url?
2. I was able to add dynamic columns depends on child nodes but could not able to figure it out how to add `(onNodeSelect)` event only to the child node not the parent
3. I want the table look same as `dataTable` like each row will have `odd/even` class to give zebra rows.
4. My `sortable` and `filter` for `treeTable` parent nodes are not working

Here is my view code ...

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="ui-grid-col-8">
  <p-treeTable [value]="aggregatelazyFiles" [style]="{'margin-top':'50px'}" (onNodeExpand)="nodeExpand($event)" (onNodeCollapse)="nodeCollapse($event)" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedFile" (onNodeSelect)="getHourlyProductsSummary(selectedFile)">
   <p-header>Daily Products Count Lazy Loading</p-header>
    <p-column *ngFor="let col of cols" [field]="col.field" [header]="col.header" [sortable]="true" [filter]="true" filterPlaceholder="Search" ></p-column>
  </p-treeTable>
 </div>
</div>
```